# Lazy Loading for Owned Types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, ef-core-3.1

I am moving my first steps towards Domain Driven Design using Entity Framework Core. I have a `User` entity that, in a simplified version, has only `Id` and `ProfilePhoto`. However, I want to store profile photos in a different table, that is why I created an Owned Type containing the profile photo and configured in this way:

User:

```
public class User
{
    private int id;
    public int Id => this.id;

    //private UserProfilePhoto userProfilePhoto;
    public virtual UserProfilePhoto UserProfilePhoto { get; set; }

    private User()
    {
    }

    public static User Create(byte[] profilePhoto)
    {
        var user = new User();
        user.UserProfilePhoto = new UserProfilePhoto(profilePhoto);

        return user;
    }

    public void SetProfilePhoto(byte[] profilePhoto)
    {
        this.UserProfilePhoto = new UserProfilePhoto(profilePhoto);
    }
}
```

UserProfilePhoto:

```
public class UserProfilePhoto
{
    public byte[] ProfilePhoto { get; private set; }

    public UserProfilePhoto(byte[] profilePhoto)
    {
        this.ProfilePhoto = profilePhoto;
    }
}
```

DbContext configuration:

```
public class ModelContext : DbContext
{
    public ModelContext(DbContextOptions<ModelContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        OnUserModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected void OnUserModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasKey(u => u.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(u => u.Id)
            .HasField("id");

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .OwnsOne(u => u.UserProfilePhoto, builder =>
            {
                builder.ToTable("UserProfilePhoto");

                builder.Property(u => u.ProfilePhoto)
                    .IsRequired();
            });
    }
}
```

I chose to use an Owned type because I want the profile photo to be accessible only from the user entity. with a one-to-one mapping, I could still access the `UserProfilePhoto` table using `context.Set<UserProfilePhoto>()` for example and, for what I read about DDD aggregates, this could mean skipping `User` business logic.
So, I migrated and the database model is just like I expected it to be: the `UserProfilePhoto` table with a primary and foreign key to `User.Id`.

Obviously in my queries I do not want to load the entire `User` entity every time, so I enabled Lazy Loading, unsuccessfully. This is the code I tried in a unit test:

```
protected ModelContext GetModelContext(DbContextOptionsBuilder<ModelContext> builder)
{
    builder
        .UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .EnableDetailedErrors();

    var ctx = new ModelContext(builder.Options);
    ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

    return ctx;
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ModelContext>()
        .UseSqlServer(...);
    var ctx = this.GetModelContext(builder);
    var user = User.Create(new byte[] { });

    try
    {
        await ctx.Users.AddAsync(user);
        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

        var users = ctx.Users;

        foreach (var u in users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(u.Id);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        ctx.Users.Remove(user);
        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        ctx.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    }
}
```

And here the SQL generated:

```
SELECT [u].[Id], [u0].[UserId], [u0].[ProfilePhoto]
FROM [Users] AS [u]
LEFT JOIN [UserProfilePhoto] AS [u0] ON [u].[Id] = [u0].[UserId]
```

I do not exactly know if it works, but injecting an `ILazyLoader` is not an solution for me, on the other hand, it feels like dirtying the model.

My doubt is that Owned types do not bind to the principal entity through actual navigation properties, so creating proxy for them is not supported.

What is wrong with my approach? Is it DDD? And if so, how can I lazily load owned entities?

I found an [issue on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10787) related to this, although it does not answer my question.

---

**Edit**

my goal is to prevent the access to the `UserProfilePhoto` table from EF api (See comments). If I managed to do this, then protecting my `UserProfilePhoto` class and encapsulating it in the `User` class would be easy, something like this:

`User`

```
...
protected virtual UserProfilePhoto UserProfilePhoto { get; set; }

public void SetProfilePhoto(byte[] profilePhoto)
{
    this.UserProfilePhoto.SetProfilePhoto(profilePhoto);
}

public byte[] GetProfilePhoto()
{
    return this.UserProfilePhoto.ProfilePhoto;
}
...
```

I tried this code with a one-to-one mapping and works perfectly, even with lazy loading. How could I do this with only Owned Types? are there other ways?

Comment: IMHO It doesn't sound like you want an owned type, just a `.HasOne(...).WithOne(...)` relationship. You could override `DbContext.Set<T>()` so it throws when `typeof(T) == typeof(UserProfilePhoto)` ?

Comment: that is true, it is conceptually a one to one relationship. But as far as I know EF would have to track both related entities in my case, which means I would need to override `DbContext.Find`, `DbContext.Entry` and maybe more... Moreover, overriding these methods means checking for business invariants in the data layer, which is a DDD anti-pattern. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Well, there's probably nothing you can do about `.Set<User>().Select(u => u.UserProfilePhoto)` anyway to bypass anything.

Comment: Please see the edit. In short, modifying my model making the navigation property protected I could prevent that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF Core loads owned types automatically when the owner gets loaded (from [Owned Entity Types: Querying owned types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#querying-owned-types))

> When querying the owner the owned types will be included by default. It is not necessary to use the Include method, even if the owned types are stored in a separate table.

Therefore using owned types does not fulfill your requirement of being loaded only on demand.

(You can tinker with `Metadata.PrincipalToDependent.SetIsEagerLoaded(false)` etc., but this is very much unsupported, unlikely to work in all cases and could break any time.)

#### Options without using owned types (in order of recommendation)

- Override `DbContext.Set<>()`, `DbContext.Find()` etc. and throw if called inappropriately
- Implement a traditional custom Unit-of-Work and Repository pattern, that gives you full control over the API exposed (trades flexibility for control)
- Add an expression visitor early to the query pipeline (register `IQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory` and derive from `RelationalQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory`), that throws if a `DbSet<UserProfilePhoto>` is used anywhere in the query
- Provide your own `IDbSetSource` (and `InternalDbSet`) implementation (both internal) and throw if called inappropriately

#### Overriding `DbContext` methods

Generally, just overriding `DbContext.Set<>()`, `DbContext.Find()` etc. should be the simplest solution. You could decorate the types that you don't want to be queried directly with a custom attribute and then simply just check, that `TEntity` etc. has not have been decorated with this custom attribute.

For easier maintainability, all the overridden methods can be moved to a base class, that can also perform some runtime check to ensure, that all methods in question have been overridden (of course those checks could also be done by a unit test).

Here is a sample demonstrating this approach:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public sealed class DontRootQueryMeAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
    
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }

        public virtual UserProfilePhoto UserProfilePhoto { get; set; }

        public static User Create(byte[] profilePhoto)
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                UserProfilePhoto = new UserProfilePhoto(profilePhoto)
            };

            return user;
        }
    }

    [DontRootQueryMeAttribute]
    public class UserProfilePhoto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] ProfilePhoto { get; private set; }

        public UserProfilePhoto(byte[] profilePhoto)
        {
            ProfilePhoto = profilePhoto;
        }
    }
    
    public abstract class ModelContextBase : DbContext
    {
        private static readonly string[] OverriddenMethodNames =
        {
            nameof(DbContext.Set),
            nameof(DbContext.Query),
            nameof(DbContext.Find),
            nameof(DbContext.FindAsync),
        };

        static ModelContextBase()
        {
            var type = typeof(ModelContextBase);

            var overriddenMethods = type
                .GetRuntimeMethods()
                .Where(
                    m => m.IsPublic &&
                         !m.IsStatic &&
                         OverriddenMethodNames.Contains(m.Name) &&
                         m.GetRuntimeBaseDefinition() != null)
                .Select(m => m.GetRuntimeBaseDefinition())
                .ToArray();

            var missingOverrides = type.BaseType
                .GetRuntimeMethods()
                .Where(
                    m => m.IsPublic &&
                         !m.IsStatic &&
                         OverriddenMethodNames.Contains(m.Name) &&
                         !overriddenMethods.Contains(m))
                .ToArray();

            if (missingOverrides.Length > 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    $"The '{nameof(ModelContextBase)}' class is missing overrides for {string.Join(", ", missingOverrides.Select(m => m.Name))}.");
            }
        }
        
        private void EnsureRootQueryAllowed<TEntity>()
            => EnsureRootQueryAllowed(typeof(TEntity));

        private void EnsureRootQueryAllowed(Type type)
        {
            var rootQueriesAllowed = type.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DontRootQueryMeAttribute)) == null;
            
            if (!rootQueriesAllowed)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Directly querying for '{type.Name}' is prohibited.");
        }

        public override DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
        {
            EnsureRootQueryAllowed<TEntity>();
            return base.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public override DbQuery<TQuery> Query<TQuery>()
        {
            EnsureRootQueryAllowed<TQuery>();
            return base.Query<TQuery>();
        }

        public override object Find(Type entityType, params object[] keyValues)
        {
            EnsureRootQueryAllowed(entityType);
            return base.Find(entityType, keyValues);
        }

        public override ValueTask<object> FindAsync(Type entityType, params object[] keyValues)
        {
            EnsureRootQueryAllowed(entityType);
            return base.FindAsync(entityType, keyValues);
        }

        public override ValueTask<object> FindAsync(Type entityType, object[] keyValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            EnsureRootQueryAllowed(entityType);
            return base.FindAsync(entityType, keyValues, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override TEntity Find<TEntity>(params object[] keyValues)
        {
            EnsureRootQueryAllowed<TEntity>();
            return base.Find<TEntity>(keyValues);
        }

        public override ValueTask<TEntity> FindAsync<TEntity>(params object[] keyValues)
        {
            EnsureRootQueryAllowed<TEntity>();
            return base.FindAsync<TEntity>(keyValues);
        }

        public override ValueTask<TEntity> FindAsync<TEntity>(object[] keyValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            EnsureRootQueryAllowed<TEntity>();
            return base.FindAsync<TEntity>(keyValues, cancellationToken);
        }

        // Add other overrides as needed...
    }
    
    public class ModelContext : ModelContextBase
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(
                    @"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So63887500_01")
                .UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(b => b
                    .AddConsole()
                    .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            OnUserModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        protected void OnUserModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasOne(e => e.UserProfilePhoto)
                        .WithOne()
                        .HasForeignKey<UserProfilePhoto>(e => e.Id);
                });
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var accessingSetThrows = false;

            using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
            {
                ctx.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var user = User.Create(new byte[] { });

                ctx.Users.Add(user);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                
                // Make sure, that UserProfilePhoto cannot be queried directly.
                try
                {
                    ctx.Set<UserProfilePhoto>()
                        .ToList();
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    accessingSetThrows = true;
                }
                
                Debug.Assert(accessingSetThrows);
            }

            // No eager loading by default with owned type here.
            using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
            {
                var users = ctx.Users.ToList();

                Debug.Assert(users.Count == 1);
                Debug.Assert(users[0].UserProfilePhoto == null);
            }

            // Explicitly load profile photo.
            using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
            {
                var users = ctx.Users.ToList();
                ctx.Entry(users[0]).Reference(u => u.UserProfilePhoto).Load();
                
                Debug.Assert(users.Count == 1);
                Debug.Assert(users[0].UserProfilePhoto != null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Providing an `IQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory` implementation

An expression visitor can be used to solve the issue by using an `IQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory` implementation to search the query for a specific expression, that is only added when the new `InternalQuery()` extension method is called and throwing, if it is missing and a non-root entity is being queried. In practice, this should be good enough to make sure, that nobody in the team queries non-root objects by accident.

(You could also add an internal class instance as a constant parameter to the method call expression, that is then evaluated later in the expression visitor to ensure, that the caller really had `internal` access to the `InternalQuery()` methods. But this is just icing on the cake and unnecessary in practice, since developers could use reflection to bypass any access restrictions anyway. So I wouldn't bother to implement this.)

Here it the implementation (using a custom interface instead of a custom attribute to mark entities that should not be queried directly):

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    #region Models
    
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }

        public virtual UserProfilePhoto UserProfilePhoto { get; set; }

        public static User Create(byte[] profilePhoto)
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                UserProfilePhoto = new UserProfilePhoto(profilePhoto)
            };

            return user;
        }
    }
    
    public class UserProfilePhoto : INonRootQueryable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] ProfilePhoto { get; private set; }

        public UserProfilePhoto(byte[] profilePhoto)
        {
            ProfilePhoto = profilePhoto;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Custom implementations

    public interface INonRootQueryable
    {
    }
    
    public class CustomQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory : IQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory
    {
        private readonly QueryTranslationPreprocessorDependencies _dependencies;
        private readonly RelationalQueryTranslationPreprocessorDependencies _relationalDependencies;

        public CustomQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory(
            QueryTranslationPreprocessorDependencies dependencies,
            RelationalQueryTranslationPreprocessorDependencies relationalDependencies)
        {
            _dependencies = dependencies;
            _relationalDependencies = relationalDependencies;
        }

        public virtual QueryTranslationPreprocessor Create(QueryCompilationContext queryCompilationContext)
            => new CustomQueryTranslationPreprocessor(
                _dependencies,
                _relationalDependencies,
                queryCompilationContext);
    }

    public class CustomQueryTranslationPreprocessor : RelationalQueryTranslationPreprocessor
    {
        public CustomQueryTranslationPreprocessor(
            QueryTranslationPreprocessorDependencies dependencies,
            RelationalQueryTranslationPreprocessorDependencies relationalDependencies,
            QueryCompilationContext queryCompilationContext)
            : base(dependencies, relationalDependencies, queryCompilationContext)
        {
        }

        public override Expression Process(Expression query)
        {
            query = new ThrowOnNoneRootQueryableViolationExpressionVisitor().Visit(query);
            return base.Process(query);
        }
    }
    
    public class ThrowOnNoneRootQueryableViolationExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private bool _isInternalQuery;

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition() == CustomQueryableExtensions.InternalQueryMethodInfo)
            {
                _isInternalQuery = true;
                return node.Arguments[0];
            }
            
            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
        {
            var expression = base.VisitConstant(node);
            
            // Throws if SomeEntity in a DbSet<SomeEntity> implements INonRootQueryable and the query was not chained
            // to the `InternalQuery()` extension method.
            return !_isInternalQuery &&
                   node.Type.IsGenericType &&
                   node.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<>) &&
                   node.Type.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 1 &&
                   typeof(INonRootQueryable).IsAssignableFrom(node.Type.GenericTypeArguments[0])
                ? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Directly querying for '{node.Type.Name}' is prohibited.")
                : expression;
        }
    }
    
    internal static class CustomQueryableExtensions
    {
        internal static readonly MethodInfo InternalQueryMethodInfo
            = typeof(CustomQueryableExtensions)
                .GetTypeInfo()
                .GetDeclaredMethods(nameof(InternalQuery))
                .Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 1 &&
                             m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Namespace == $"{nameof(System)}.{nameof(System.Linq)}" &&
                             m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name.StartsWith(nameof(IQueryable)) &&
                             m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 1);

        internal static IQueryable<TSource> InternalQuery<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
            => source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(
                Expression.Call(
                    null,
                    InternalQueryMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource)),
                    source.Expression));

        internal static IQueryable<TProperty> InternalQuery<TEntity, TProperty>(this ReferenceEntry<TEntity, TProperty> source)
            where TEntity : class
            where TProperty : class
            => source.Query()
                .InternalQuery();
    }
    
    #endregion
    
    public class ModelContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            // Register the custom type IQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory.
            // Since this is a console program, we need to create our own ServiceCollection
            // for this.
            // In an ASP.NET Core application, the AddSingleton call can just be added to
            // the general service configuration method.
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
                .AddSingleton<IQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory, CustomQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory>()
                .AddScoped(
                    s => LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            optionsBuilder
                .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider) // <-- use our ServiceProvider
                .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So63887500_05")
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            OnUserModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        protected void OnUserModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasOne(e => e.UserProfilePhoto)
                        .WithOne()
                        .HasForeignKey<UserProfilePhoto>(e => e.Id);
                });
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var accessingSetThrows = false;

            using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
            {
                ctx.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var user = User.Create(new byte[] { });

                ctx.Users.Add(user);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Make sure, that UserProfilePhoto cannot be queried directly by default.
            using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    ctx.Set<UserProfilePhoto>()
                        .ToList();
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    accessingSetThrows = true;
                }
                
                Debug.Assert(accessingSetThrows);
            }

            // Make sure, that UserProfilePhoto can be queried directly, when using the `InternalQuery()` extension
            // method.
            using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
            {
                var userProfilePhotos = ctx.Set<UserProfilePhoto>()
                    .InternalQuery()
                    .ToList();
                
                Debug.Assert(userProfilePhotos.Count == 1);
            }

            // No eager loading of referenced types by default.
            using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
            {
                var users = ctx.Users.ToList();

                Debug.Assert(users.Count == 1);
                Debug.Assert(users[0].UserProfilePhoto == null);
            }

            // Eager loading of referenced types is allowed, when using the `InternalQuery()` extension method.
            using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
            {
                var users = ctx.Users
                    .Include(u => u.UserProfilePhoto)
                    .InternalQuery()
                    .ToList();

                Debug.Assert(users.Count == 1);
                Debug.Assert(users[0].UserProfilePhoto != null);
            }

            // Explicitly load profile photo, when using the `InternalQuery()` extension method.
            using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
            {
                var users = ctx.Users.ToList();
                ctx.Entry(users[0])
                    .Reference(u => u.UserProfilePhoto)
                    .InternalQuery()
                    .Load();

                Debug.Assert(users.Count == 1);
                Debug.Assert(users[0].UserProfilePhoto != null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically what I would suggest. With two additions. (1) Due to (current) EFC explicit/lazy implementation specifics (lazy loading via explicit loading, explicit loading via execution of tracking query) and tracking query restriction of owned entity types, they cannot use lazy/explicit loading, even though the default eager loading could be controlled with the mentioned metadata API. (2)  Applying restriction with custom `IDbSetSource` / `InternalDbSet` doesn't seem to be an option, because it also would prevent the lazy/explicit loading (again due to implementation specifics)...

Comment: ... And adding custom `IEntityFinderSource` and `EntityFinder` seems too much.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have experimented a little with metadata API and are definitely unstable, but the first time I used them, they felt like the lesser evil. I usually avoid to override EF API (same for expression visitors) because the overridden implementation could grow in complexity in no time if overused, then maintaining them is a hard task. If I go this way, the custom attribute is a great idea. I agree with @IvanStoev where he says the third option is probably too much

Comment: When the overridden methods are abstracted away in their own base class, they should be simpler to maintain. The expression visitor approach has the advantage, that it will be complete despite what `DbContext`/`DbSet` method is being called, even if methods/overloads are added to `DbContext` in the future by EF Core. However, for the expression visitor to work across all providers (which might have already implemented `IQueryTranslationPreprocessorFactory` on their own), the registration logic needs to be done with care.

Comment: Could you provide in your answer an example or a pseudo-implementation of how would you use an expression visitor please? Sorry but not even your thoughts on the overriden methods are clear to me: how could that be simpler to maintain? Thanks.

Comment: As it turns out, the expression visitor implementation will also throw when explicitly querying for `UserProfilePhoto`, which might be not what you want. You could extend it, that it does not throw when certain entities are queried together though. However, since this implementation would get more complicated, I also added sample code for the much simpler overriding `DbContext` methods approach, which does work as expected, and clarified how to improve maintainability.

Comment: Well, first of all thanks for your work. Regarding the overridden DbContext based solution, just a few things: good thinking in placing in the static constructor the check to ensure all necessary methods have been overridden. I believe it could be simplified, but I do not care now. Instead I would definitely avoid to retrieve every time the custom attributes in `EnsureRootQueryAllowed`. Reflection has a remarkable performance load, I would have used a `Dictionary<Type, bool>` for example and fill it with a GetOrInsert strategy so that the `GetCustomAttribute` is called once for each type. ...

Comment: ... But my main goal is to allow creation, deletion or updation of the `UserProfilePhoto` only from the `User` entity. as well as `Find` and `Set`, I would have to override `Add(Range)`, `Remove(Range)`, `Update` and basically the `ChangeTracker` API too. The size of this base class would grow a lot and work just like an wrapper. That is why since from the start I did not want to go this way: I like the idea of a custom attribute, but still does not solve the real issue optimally.

Comment: Yes, this is the intended design here. It does not really grow a lot, but just adds checks to all methods you need to control, which is not unreasonable. It keeps providing the user of the `DbContext` with some of the flexibility of EF Core.

Comment: I added another option to the list: Implementing your custom Unit-of-Work and Repository patterns. Since you want full control over the exposed API and don't want to expose the flexibility that EF Core provides to the users of the Context and don't want to override the `DbContext` itself, implementing a traditional Unit-of-Work and Repository pattern is about the only standard approach left from my point of view. It trades the flexibility that EF Core provides in its own Unit-of-Work (`DbContext`) and Repository (`DbSet`) implementations for a maximum of control.

Comment: While the latter approach is not recommended for EF Core users in general, because it just adds another layer of Unit-of-Work and Repository over what EF Core already provides, it should be the right approach for your specific requirements, where you don't want to deviate in any way from a traditional DDD implementation. It is full compliant with DDD but a bit more cumbersome to implement in the long run, because of the traditional repository pattern approach (assuming you want to avoid the typical repository anti-patterns), in case your solution contains a lot of repositories.

Comment: I also just added descriptions about two solutions for fixing the expression visitor approach to my answer. They should work in the way you want when combined with non-public navigation properties. If I have a little bit of time in the evening, I might add implementations for them to the sample code.

Comment: Alright, I added a fully working expression visitor implementation sample and a bit of description to the answer. At least one of theses approaches should be a suitable choice for you.

Comment: None of them is the perfect solution and I was prepared to this when I put the bounty. I am not so fixated on protecting my `UserProfilePhoto`, for this reason implementing a Repository pattern is unnecessary in my opinion. Thank you so much for all your hard work.

Answer (score 2):

Should bytes really be part of the domain? Do you actually run any business logic on those bytes in the user profile context? Is there really a use case where you'd want to access the bytes from within the `User` AR?

If not then perhaps it makes more sense decoupling the bytes storage from the photo's metadata and introduce a `ProfilePhoto` VO with a `storageUrl/storageId` property to locate the bytes.

Don't forget that your domain model should be designed for commands, not queries & the presentation layer.

Granted, now you can't easily have ACID properties when storing the bytes & the AR's data in the DB, but it's usually easy to cope with that with a cleanup process.

If you don't need profile photo's metadata in `User` to enforce business rules then you may also consider making `ProfilePhoto` it's own AR.

Finally, I think trying to prevent ORM misuse is unnecessary. The ORM should be seen as a low-level API which shouldn't ever be used directly to change AR states. I think it's safe to assume developers will have enough rigour to respect that rule just like they should respect the overall system's architecture. If they don't you have bigger problems. If it was as easy as adding a private modifier to a member then sure, but it seems to be needing a lot of efforts so I'd just go the pragmatic way...

Comment: This is an interesting perspective, just a few considerations: choosing between saving images in a db or straight on the file system is a debated topic. I chose db because, from what I read, it fits well for small size images. image size validation is still a part of business logic and I believe domain model is where it should stay. About making the `UserProfilePhoto` an AR of its own, you are essentially saying that, since I do not need it in `User` business logic, the efforts to keep it updated with `User` are limited and is a good tradeoff. Am I right? still, how to protect it from EF api?

Comment: Well, what I'm saying is that if there are no invariants to protect between other `User` information and information related to the `UserProfilePhoto`, then you don't have to aggregate all that info into `User`. In other words, if both `User` and `UserProfilePhoto` are changed, should operations be conflicting or not? Furthermore, handling the bytes storage outside of the ARs themselves while preserving bytes metadata (description, size, etc.) within the AR would remove the need for lazy loading. I dont think those bytes belong to the domain since they aren't processed there.

Comment: I agree. We can say they are not related with regard to business invariants and from a domain model perspective, they can be separated. However, when I think of a possible update of the User entity, that would imply modifying 2 different ARs. Is it the correct way here, in your opinion? About decoupling image data outside of db, I am not convinced. I have other informations inside my model that are not really processed there but only validated, still they belong there. If yours is an advice to get rid of lazy loading cleverly then it is a good one, but I think I have no reason to get rid of it

Comment: Why would you have to modify the User AR to change UserProfilePhoto AR details? As for the bytes storage then yes I think the image's representation may be more of an infrastructure concern than a domain concern (at least in the user/identity/profile context). Domain experts are probably not very interested about bytes size, format, etc but the application does for security & efficiency purposes... unless you run AI analysis and perhaps have paid plans for hosting better quality photos, but that would most likely be in another context.

Comment: Finally, I think encapsulation violations through the ORMs API are unimportant. The model should make it hard to use the code incorrectly, but one can always find a way to abuse it voluntarily like using the ORM directly or even reflection to set private members. You can't prevent a developer to mess things up deliberately

Comment: I have a PUT API that performs a total update on the `User` entity. Should I change 2 AR when there is ideally only 1 entity involved? About EF's API, Sure there are multiple ways to mess things up, but owned types seemed to me a way to make things more complicated for the "ill-intentioned" developer. Good point in observing that domain experts do not care about infrastructure concerns, that would lead me towards your solution. I am still not completely convinced about all of this but that is probably due to my inexperience in this field.

Comment: Well, sending an update command is not very DDD like. Does it really make sense to change the profile photo among with a bunch of other profile info? DDD aligns better with task-based UIs, which makes intentions/use cases explicit like having a dedicated ChangeProfilePhoto command. Not saying UserProfilePhoto must be a seperate AR though, it depends on business rules.

Comment: And I still think trying to prevent ORM misuse is unecessary. The ORM should be seen as a low-level API which shouldn't ever be used directly to change AR states. I think it's safe to assume developers will have enough rigour to respect that rule just like they should respect the overall system architecture. If they dont you have bigger problems. If it was as easy as adding a private modifier to a member then sure, but it seems to be needing a lot of efforts so I'd just go the pragmatic way...

Comment: It might be not very DDD like but that is the API I have to implement and it is without a doubt RESTful. I surely cannot try to convince the client to send a bunch of PATCH to update the `User` entity. About the ORM misuse, you are right, this is definitely the case to be pragmatic.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .OwnsOne(u => u.UserProfilePhoto, builder =>
    {
        builder.Metadata.IsOwnership = false;
        builder.Metadata.IsRequired = false;
        builder.Metadata.PrincipalToDependent.SetIsEagerLoaded(false);

        builder.ToTable("UserProfilePhoto");

        builder.Property(u => u.ProfilePhoto)
            .IsRequired();
    });
```

I do not like it and I guess EF allows you to configure that in other, more clear, ways. I am not accepting this answer, hoping someone else could point me in the right direction.

---

EDIT: proxy works this way but when a `User` is deleted, the association with the `UserProfilePhoto` is severed:

> The association between entities '`User`' and '`UserProfilePhoto`' with
> the key value '{UserId: 1}' has been severed but the relationship is
> either marked as 'Required' or is implicitly required because the
> foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be
> deleted when a required relationship is severed, then setup the
> relationship to use cascade deletes.

I even tried to specify through metadata the `DeleteBehaviour.Cascade` option but it probably breaks an internal constraint.

Moreover, it is now accessible via `DbContext.Set<UserProfilephoto>()`, which is not what I want.